# --enable_sendmail in GAE 1.7.6 has been changed

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, sendmail

Not entirely sure if this is specific to me or not, however after recently updating to GAE 1.7.6 Dev server for Mac I've discovered that the flag:

--enable_sendmail

was causing the server to not launch. After doing some Google searching with no results I realised that despite not being documented at all in the recent changes list on GAE pages (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver), the way to fix this error was to change it to:

--enable_sendmail=yes

More than anything I am documenting this here in case anyone else has this same error and is looking for a solution. It took me quite a while.

Perhaps someone over at App Engine could be kind enough to update their docs?

Comment: Did you link to the right docs? You linked to the old dev_appserver docs.

Comment: The official release notes here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes link through to the devserver page which documents how to run sendmail here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_Mail - which is still wrong.